# Naming confusion : Why it is not called Decoding but Encoding in every browser?

Tags: browser, encoding, decoding

In browsers such as Firefox, Chrome and IE, there is an option called Encoding. It is used to decode the HTML documents into different languages.

As far as I know, say, if I choose, "Encoding (Unicode UTF-8)" in my browser, the browser will treat the HTML page to be decoded in UTF-8 format.

My question is why is it called "Encoding" instead of "Decoding"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called encoding based on the idea that the the file you are downloading is *encoded* in a particular format, in your case Unicode UTF-8.

When a file is encoded in this format we say that its *encoding* is Unicode UTF-8.  It requires a UTF-8 decoder, but it is the encoding of the file itself which the program is talking about.

Comment: But for the browsers, they are actually doing Decoding of my HTML document, aren't they?

Comment: Yes, but you are telling the browser about the actual encoding of the file.  Granted you could look at it the other way and say that it should use a particular decoder, but what if you have multiple weirdly named decoders for UTF that are all subtly different?  Surely telling it about the actual file encoding and letting it decide what decoder to use makes a little more sense?

Comment: Each document has a property called its Encoding and this option allows you to override that property.  Some operations such as saving a page to disk may just write the name of the encoding and not actually decode anything.